# XmlStar usage in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, canonicalization, c14n

I am trying to canonicalize a few xml documents.
As I see it can be achieved by using XmlStar by executing a CMD command

```
xml c14n --exc-without-comments test_xml.xml > test_xml_canonicalize.xml
```

My question is can the same result be achieved with C# using XmlDsigC14NTransform class but without RSA signing  and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
     using (MemoryStream msIn = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.InnerXml)))
     {
         var t = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(false);
         t.LoadInput(msIn);
         MemoryStream o = t.GetOutput() as MemoryStream;
         string c14N = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(o?.ToArray() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
         Console.WriteLine(c14N);
     }
```